# How do I use JQuery to iterate a form from the bottom to the top, most nested element first without knowing the id of the deepest element beforehand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic form builder that create a form in an MVC web application.
It's arranged into sections and questions, sections contain questions or other sections.

The plan was to have some sections open based on the input of certain questions (so for instance checking a box saying you own a car makes the section on car details enabled). All sections which could be opened need to start disabled/hidden (so they can be opened on the relevant input).

All sections and questions have an id although unfortunately I won't know what these are until the page is loaded as Id's are generated dynamically, so i can't just start iterating up from a known deepest element, I have to find it first and then iterate..

I have no idea how to iterate through from the bottom up up, deepest first.
If I iterate from top to bottom, any nested openable sections within openable won't get disabled as the parent will be deactivated before it can be.

Help would be VERY MUCH appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: If you want the opposite of depth-first traversal, it could be as simple as just `.reverse()`ing the jQuery collection.  I can't tell from your question whether this is actually what you're looking for.

Comment: I need to iterate each html input element starting from the bottom of the page, and deepest first. This is because I need to check if each can be opened by answering a question higher up (to make sure they all begin hidden).

Comment: Marked down twice in two minutes for asking a clear question (which from my prior searches on stack overflow hasn't been answered in a way which works for my problem)...welcome to stack overflow.

Does the welcome pack also include being spat on and shouted at in public?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at JQuery's [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function?

Example:

```
function openParent(jq_element) {
    jq_element.show();
    if(jq_element.parent().length) {
        openParent(jq_element.closest());
    }
}

$('input').each(function() {
    openParent($(this));
});
```

You could also try something with the parents() function, you can find the differences on the JQuery documentation pages:

**.closest()**

- Begins with the current element
- Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied
  selector
- The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element for each
  element in the original set, in document order

**.parents()**

- Begins with the parent element
- Travels up the DOM tree to the
  document's root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary
  collection; it then filters that collection based on a selector if
  one is supplied
- The returned jQuery object contains zero or more
  elements for each element in the original set, in reverse document
  order

---

**UPDATE**

To find the most deepest element, you could iterate over all elements that don't have a child element (so all 'deepest' elements):

```
$('body *:not(:has("*"))');
```

If you need to open sections based on checkboxes that are checked or not (like your own a car example) You could do something like this:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    $(  '#' + $(this).data('referenced-section-id-from-current-element')  ).show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D

Unfortunately I won't know the Id of the element before the page loads. If I could know which the deepest element would be it wouldn't be that hard to just iterate up, but in this case I won't what the Id's will be (as they are dynamically generated using data from the mvc controller.

Comment: @JohnPalpatine I updated the answer with an example to find the deepest elements.